# Changing labels text when button is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I just downloaded Xamarin forms, and I'm trying to make an app that changes the text of a label when a button is clicked.
I'm trying to do this by putting `labelname.Text = "Text"` in the button click event. My problem is that the name of my label doesn't exist in the current context. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you put your code, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Make sure you added a property "x:Name=WhateverName" ex.

2- Try rebuild your solution

- x:Name creates a reference to the control as a private member in your code-behind. So you can access it

Answer (score 5):

> MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Label x:Name="label"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

> MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = "Changed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the button click event, you need to call a function.

So you need to first define a function which changes the label's text and thn call it in the button click event.